# $f(z) = \cosh^3z -2$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z) = \cosh^3z -2$

I wish to evaluate $f(i)$.

Now: $\cosh z = \frac{1}{2}(e^z + e^{-z})$

for $z=i$ this gives: $\cosh i = \frac{1}{2}(e^i + e^{-i})$

But now I am stuck. How do I get this to some Cartesian form?

Comment: $e^{it} = \cos(t) + i\sin(t)$ would be helpful.

Comment: Tried that already, now $t=1$, so I get an equation in $\cos (1) + i sin (1)$, and $\cos (-1) + i sin (-1)$, Secondly I know that $\cosh z = \cos (iz)$ In that case I get: $\cos^3 (-1) -2$

Comment: rectangular form is $x+iy$ where $x,y$ are real.  Soooo…..

Comment: Correct, $x=0, and y=1$, that I figured out my self ;-)

Comment: I thought it was quite an easy question, but it is harder than I thought.

Comment: I would leave it in exponential form while cubing it.

Comment: I did that before: we get: $e^{3z} + 3e^z + 3e^{-z} + e^{-3z}$, that doesn't make it easier

Comment: You have $f(i) = \cos^3 1 - 2$ what is wrong with that?

Comment: $\cosh i = \cos 1$ Cube both sides, equate to2, solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
e^i &= \cos 1 + i \sin 1, \\ e^{-i} &= \cos (-1) + i \sin (-1) = \cos 1 - i \sin 1. \end{align}$$
Hence
$$\cosh i = \frac{1}{2}(e^i + e^{-i}) = \frac{\cos 1 + i \sin 1 + \cos 1 - i \sin 1}{2} = \cos 1,$$
and
$$\cosh^3 i - 2 = \cos^3 1 - 2.$$  The imaginary part is $0$.